# How was it possible to use the theme music of Mission Impossible in Ace Ventura Pet Detective?

Tags: soundtrack, ace-ventura-pet-detective

I was watching [Ace Ventura Pet Detective](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109040/) today and observed a very interesting thing. The soundtrack of [Mission Impossible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission:_Impossible_%28film%29) is used in a scene where Jim Carrey is seen entering the bathroom of Camp and jumping from the window of the bathroom and reaching the pool. The soundtrack starts with this scene:

[image: Ace Entering Camps bathroom]

So how is this possible given the fact the first Mission Impossible released on 1996 whereas Ace Ventura released in 1994?

Comment: TIL how old I am, because people aren't even aware that TV programmes I watched as a kid existed. But upvoted anyway.

Comment: It doesn't even occur that maybe there was something before the Tom Cruise film?

Comment: @OrangeDog I am from a different country and different culture. So I am not aware of everything in Hollywood.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The song you are talking about was the theme tune of the TV series [Mission: Impossible (1966–1973).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theme_from_Mission:_Impossible) It returned to television for two seasons from 1988 to 1990.

Original theme From YouTube:

The Mission Impossible movie is based on the TV series.

In 1996, the theme was remade by U2 members Adam Clayton and Larry Mullen, Jr. for the soundtrack for the [Mission Impossible](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117060/) movie. This means that [Ace Ventura Pet Detective](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109040/)  used the older version of the song from the TV series.

Comment: Btw, the TV series was revived in [1988](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094511/) for two seasons.

Comment: @Mistu4u - *Do* check out the TV series (both of them). They are miles and miles better than the movies.

Comment: Kids these days... *grin*